# Duals of Deltahedra

Tags: terminology, polyhedra

What are the names of the duals of the Snub Disphenoid and the Triaugmented Triangular Prism?  I built models of the eight convex deltahedra and their duals using spherical magnets as vertices, and want to know what to call them all.  The other duals were all Johnson Solids, except for the dual of the Gyroelongated Square Dipyramid (the Square Truncated Trapezohedron).

Comment: Johnson solids are apparently denoted by $J_{\cdot}$. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid, The Snub Disphenoid and the Triaugmented Triangular Prism are numbers $84$ and $51$, respectively. So, for the snub guy, you may say $J_{84}$, and for its dual, you may say, e.g. $J_{84}^d$. You may not count these as names however :)

Comment: Do you have pictures?

Answer (score 2):

Not all polyhedra have names.  For example, of the 34 [heptahedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptahedron), only 4 have names(hexagonal pyramid, pentagonal prism, elongated triangular pyramid, and diminished cube). This dual isn't special enough to be named.